Where is my dub (backup) configuration?
I made a successful backup through Kubuntu Systems Setting to Dropbox. I can read the backup, etc.
As far as I know Kubuntu uses the bup program for backups.
Where does Kubuntu stores the settings for bup? Not in ~/.bub (not created) and I can´t find it in ~/.config or any other file.

The package for Kubuntu backups is kup-backup.From the package description:
Kup is a backup tool for KDE's Plasma desktop created for helping people to keep
up-to-date backups of their personal files.

It could indeed make use of bup which is a package recommended by kup-backup, depending on your distribution this package may be installed or not.
The backup plans are stored in the file ~/.config/kuprc. It's a plain text file.

kup-backup is indeed "installed, automatic", but there is no executable.
kup-backup uses bup or rcopy.
I have no file ~/.config/kuprc  or anything like it, so my quesyion remains the same/

@RabanePaco That's strange. Please edit your question and add details about your Kubuntu version.

Kubuntu: standard installation of 22.04
(I thought I had answered this already).

@RabanePaco What I described in the answer is how it works in 22.04 plasma-desktop. If you really don't have that file, I'm out of ideas, sorry.
